# Magento --> Want to display the list of product in grid with pagination and search bar in frontend

Tags: php, magento, pagination

I just want to display the list of vendor product in grid view with pagination and search bar. I have searched in google but I didnt get a clear solution for that. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Refer Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php file For Collection and phtml file pls refer catalog/product/list.php file

you can get all stuff for display your product at frontend it may helpful to you.

and create cms page`{{ block type="Your block type" template="your phtml file"  }}`